# Logstash (ELK): Enrich IP with hostname (based off a file). - (No direct connect w/ DNS/AD)

Tags: logstash, kibana, elk

Trying to figure out how to enrich the data being ingested (Network Data) Zeek/Suricata.  I would like to either show Hostname vice IP, or more preferably add another field for hostname based off the IP address.

Have a file with IP -> Hostnames (CSV) currently could be anything other format if required.  Unable to get IP to Hostname with DNS or Active Directory or any other connected means.

I know in Splunk you could do lookup tables, but unsure how to accomplish the same in the ELK stack to view the results in Kibana.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in logstash using a [translate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-translate.html) filter, which requires a two-column CSV file (or YML, or JSON). You could try

```
translate {
    source => "[fieldWithIP]"
    dictionary_path => "/path/to/mapping.csv"
    target => "[fieldForHostname]"
}
```

this would add a new field called [fieldForHostname] if the value of [fieldWithIP] is found in column 1 of the mapping.csv

Comment: This would replace IP to Hostname right?

Comment: No, it would add a field.